# getJSON GET 404 - Как извлечь данные?

Tags: javascript, json

Пытаюсь получить данные

```
$.getJSON("/getbooking",function(data){ ...
```

и получаю ошибку GET http../getbooking 404/ При этом, если я запущу свой скрипт на локалхосте и укажу полный линк до своей функции на сайте, данные подгружаются, подскажите, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: в.$ getJson надо писать путь до json файла ..примерно так site.ru/main.json или просто $.getJson("main.json", init);

Comment: @UbuntuUser но список формируется при обращении к функции, списку свойственно постоянно изменяться.. Тут другое - почему я могу получить данные только из другого источника, а сам, находясь на странице сайта и обращаясь в запросу, который в роуте прописал, получить данные не могу(

Comment: в общем $.getJson пишется первым параметром url json файла а потом обработчик уже ...а это будет function или другое что то не важно - надо просто обработать как то .. в общем про первый параметр понимаете да ?

Comment: @UbuntuUser я сделал иначе, при открытии страницы моя модель получает данные и сохраняет их в json файл, далее моя функция извлекает эти данные из файла, единственный момент - не будет ли проседать скрипт...